# Stripe payments on Google AppEngine using Java - com.stripe.exception.ApiConnectionException: IOException during API request to Stripe

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, stripe-payments

need helpppp .. kinda stuck with following issue -

I am working on web application and using Stripe payments and simply trying to do Charge using following code. User inputs credit card info, it creates Token successfully ..however, Stripe Charge always fails with following error. I do not have any internet connection issue - maybe something to do with appengine not accepting response back from Stripe??

Stripe Charge Link - https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create

**: com.stripe.exception.ApiConnectionException: IOException during API request to Stripe (https://api.stripe.com): api.stripe.com Please check your internet connection and try again.** If this problem persists,you should check Stripe's service status at https://twitter.com/stripestatus, or let us know at support@stripe.com.

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    .
    .
    .
    Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_****************";
    Map<String, Object> chargeParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    chargeParams.put("amount", 999);
    chargeParams.put("currency", "usd");
    chargeParams.put("description", "Charge for test@gmail.com");
    chargeParams.put("source", "tok_visa");

    try {
        Charge.create(chargeParams);  /// <<<-- it fails here, no issue with internet connection. 
    } catch (StripeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    .
    .
    .
    } //end of doPost
```

error log:

```
<stderr>: com.stripe.exception.ApiConnectionException: IOException during API request to Stripe (https://api.stripe.com): api.stripe.com Please check your internet connection and try again. If this problem persists,you should check Stripe's service status at https://twitter.com/stripestatus, or let us know at support@stripe.com.
at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.makeUrlConnectionRequest(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:444)
at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.getStripeResponse(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:592)
at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.rawRequest(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:501)
at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.staticRequest(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:526)
at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.request(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:83)
at com.stripe.net.ApiResource.request(ApiResource.java:204)
at com.stripe.model.Charge.create(Charge.java:372)
at com.stripe.model.Charge.create(Charge.java:364)
at com.jagdish.ViewController.doPost(ViewController.java:115)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1772)
```

I am using

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.stripe</groupId>
<artifactId>stripe-java</artifactId>
<version>7.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Sorry about the title with exception error msg ---- Basically I am unable to create "Charge" using Stripe payments on GAE using Java Servlets/JSP ... getting error saying "api.stripe.com Please check your internet connection and try again."

Comment: Have you already check for cert...
As in the error at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.getStripeResponse(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:592)

At line 592 :      It is written that 
 // HTTPSURLConnection verifies SSL cert by default
 return makeUrlConnectionRequest(method, url, query, options);
Src : https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stripe/net/LiveStripeResponseGetter.java

Comment: Are you 100% sure you do have a working internet connection? If you make a connection to a random external URL aside from Stripe with something like `HttpUrlConnection` does it work? Maybe App Engine has a firewall in place blocking outbound requests.

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much both of you ... . Issue is because I am using appengine free apps and I was missing <url-stream-handler>urlfetch</url-stream-handler> in appengine.xml  - per -  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/migrating-to-java8 .